# fire detection system with lm358 using arduino and labview.I want help regarding if my circuit is correct or not?VI

Tags: arduino, interface, labview

I'm a beginner working on this system ([Link](http://courseonarduino.blogspot.com/2016/04/simple-fire-detection-and-alarm-using.html)).

I build the hardware similiar to the link and I did a software implementation on Lab view as well, but only the buzzer starts when temperature is increased and the fan doesn't. How do I get the fan to work like the example in the link?

Comment: there may be a discontinuity in the middle of the busbars on the breadboard.  .. plug the fan into the busbar on the right half of the breadboard

Comment: Please add more explanations possibly with images. Question is not clear.

Comment: I've connected fan with Arduino

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem with that circuit is that it is trying to drive the fan directly from the Arduino output.

This is bad for two reasons:

1. The Arduino output can only supply a tiny bit of current through the GPIO pins.  Most certainly not enough to operate any normal fan.
2. If you had a motor that could run on the GPIO pin, you would almost certainly destroy the GPIO  output transistors in the microprocessor.  Starting and stopping a DC motor will cause high voltage peaks that can damage the transistors.  You must prevent that by using a diode to catch and dissipate the peaks.

It is also not good to drive the buzzer directly from the GPIO pins.

---

The entire functionality of that circuit could be implemented without the Arduino, and without Labview.

It is also poorly done, with no thought given to how to correctly drive external devices from a microprocessor.

The wiring diagram doesn't help much, either.  It makes it easy to slap it together, but it can't help you understand how the circuit is intended to work.

It also misleadlingly uses a light dependent resistor (LDR) to represent the infrared photodiode specified in the parts list.

---

Since I've been lambasted for judging the poor quality of the circuit provided by the site  linked to in the question (which I take to be from the  instructor,) I thought I'd go ahead and show you a better version of that circuit.  Note that I'm not criticizing the person who posted the question - the circuit is provided by someone else entirely.  I am criticizing a circuit that is being used as an example, and which may well have been provided by a course instructor.  One would hope that examples for course work would be well thought out so that the students have a fighting chance to accomplish the given tasks.  An incorrect and misleading wiring diagram from Fritzing doesn't quite make the grade.

This is the detector section:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRYpeB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the output section:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIP2lU.png)</sup>

Improvements:

1. OA1B - The LM358 is a dual op-amp.  It has two amplifiers in one package.  An unconnected amplifier as in the original circuit can oscillate and cause noise and interference on the one op-amp actually being used.  The circuit around OA1B puts both inputs in the middle of the allowed input range, and the negative feedback helps hold the output steady.  Also note that I've only shown power connections on OA1B.  OA1A and OA1B share the power pins.  As drawn and numbered, it is clear that OA1A and OA1B belong to one chip.  That allows me to show the power connections to just OP1B, and save a bunch of spaghetti wiring in the diagram - the drawing is cleaner and clearer.
2. There is now a photodiode in the circuit as the parts list clearly intended.  Either Fritzing doesn't have a photodiode part, or the instructor didn't bother to look for it.
3. The LED driver and the detector signal for the Arduino are separated.  In the original circuit. both were driven by the output of OP1A.  The output of OPA1A may not reach 5V, especially not when driving the LED as well as the digital input of the Arduino.  Using transistors as switches ensures that both (LED and digital input) receive the correct voltage.
4. Due to the inverting action of Q1 and Q2, the signal level going to the Arduino would have been inverted.  I switched the inputs to OP1A - this causes OP1A to work in inverse compared to the original circuit, but combined with Q2 provides the same signal as the original circuit.
5. Note R6.  The original circuit specified 2 fixed resistors, both 10k.  One must have been intended as the series resistor for the LED - but at 10k, the LED would have been very dim. With the 330 ohm resistor for R6, the LED will light at full brightness (it receives about 11mA of the typical maximum of 20mA for a red LED.)  Using 10k as a series resistor would have reduced the brightness by a lot - 10K works out to about  0.38mA current for the LED.
6. For the motor, I've added Q3 so that you can actually draw a bit of current for the fan to run. The Arduino GPIO pins can supply at most 20mA of current.  It would have to be a very small fan to run on that - and you risk destroying the Arduino output pin.  The 2N3904 transistor shown allows you to draw a maximum of 200mA.  Still not a lot, but much better than the Arduino's output.
7. Switching motors on and off can cause high voltage spikes that can destroy the switching transistor.  So, I have provided D3 to protect Q3 against the spikes caused by turning off the motor.  The spikes can easily reach more than the rated 100V for the 2N3904.  D3 short circuits the spike so that it can't reach more than 0.7V.
8. The buzzer is also driven through a transistor (Q4) and diode (D4) for the same reason as I used them on the motor.  The original circuit didn't specify whether the buzzer is a piezo or electromechanical.  I am therefore free to choose what buzzer I am using, and I choose an electromechanical one.  Since it uses a coil, I provide a freewheel diode(D3) to protect Q4.

The circuit editor here on the site lacks a motor symbol.  I substituted a simple box, with a note that it represents the fan motor.

I suspect that point number 6 is the real culprit in your original circuit.  The Arduino simply cannot provide enough current for a fan to run.

I'm sure that there are things that could be done better in my circuit, and I may have missed something in the original circuit that could be done better.

Those are the things that I (as an amateur) can see are wrong or less than optimal.

---

For reference, the original wiring diagram and the materials list:

Required Components:
Fan
buzzer
Photo diode ( IR receiver )
LM 385 (operational Amplifier )
Resistor 2 x 10k ohms
Potentiometer  10k ohms
LED
connecting wires
[image]

Comment: -1 -- do not use words or phrases that include assumptive value judgements: "poorly done", "with no thought given", "easy to slap it together". If your audience is novice, build them up and excite them about the larger wonders and constraints in electronic design.

Comment: @JoeFriedrichsen:  The "assumptive value judgements" come from the fact the linked project was created and posted by an instructor.  If that's what a student is being given to work from, then the student needs to know (be told) that the given materials are inadequate - a student can't judge for themselves since they don't have the experience.   And, no matter who uses it, Frtizing and its wiring diagrams are crap.